# What exactly identical mapper do in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i need more clarification about the use of identical mapper in Hadoop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did try to find out by yourself?

Comment: Yeah i tried, i found some limited source, its not enough for me,that is the reason i asked my doubts here. Anyway thanks for your visit.Just now i started to learning Bigdata Hadoop technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It directly passes the incoming key/value pair to the output.

```
Default I/P Format : TextInputFormat
Default O/P Format : TextOutputFormat
Default O/P key class : LongWritable
Default O/P value class : Text
No. of Splits = depends on the file
```

One use i could think of is when you want to change your format of the class, it could be converting textformat to sequencefileformat.

Comment: Thanks for this Vignesh.. It gives some idea